# How can ShowDialog without refresh view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, showdialog

After `ShowDialog` always reset `View` and `TextBox` control value removed. How can prevent to refresh `View`?

Register with Windsor

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IWindowManager>().ImplementedBy<WindowManager>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MyViewModel>());
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        Height="200">
 <Grid>
   <Button x:Name="ShowDialog" Width="70" Content="Show Dialog" />
   <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" Width="120"/>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
public IWindowManager WindowManager { get; set; } 
public IMyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; } 

public void ShowDialog()
{
    WindowManager.ShowDialog(MyViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will find that you receive more answers and ones of better quality if you do.

Comment: My question is obvious, this question has not been raised, Really do not know what is the problem.

Comment: If you had read the page from the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) that I provided you with a link to, then you would understand what the problem was. There is another page there that will explain how you can reopen your question. It's really a case that *you* have to help us to help you. The Help Centre is there to help users get the most out of this site. If you want to continue using this site, I'd advise that you take a few moments to read through its contents.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I edited the question.

Comment: While I understand that English is not the first language of many StackOverflow members, I would advise you to try to add a better description of your problem. However, as you have clearly taken the advise on board and attempted to improve your question, I will vote to reopen it... I cannot guarantee that the rest of the community will be so lenient, so editing and improving your description would help with this.